# Prove that matrix $A$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$, $B$ are square matrices, $B$ is symmetric and $(A+B)^2$ is symmetric, prove that $A$ is also symmetric.

Comment: Show your effort. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i used the equality (A+B)^2=((A+B)^2)^T , and  B= (B)^T

Comment: You were on the right track, see computation details below.

Comment: Where did you find this exercise? As you can see, the statement is false.

Comment: Guys thank you for the help and your time:) I guess my teacher did a typo in or smth in this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you want to prove is wrong. Take
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$
and $B$ the zero matrix. Then $B$ is symmetric, $(A+B)^2 = A^2$ is the zero matrix (and therefore symmetric), but $A$ is not symmetric.